# How to find a formula for time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

To find time complexity, I set a value for `n`, but once I iterated through the algorithm, I was unable to determine what it was. Any suggestions on how to find a formal for it so I can determine what the big-O is.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++){
  X
  X 
}
 for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
  X
}
```

`X` are just operations in the algorithm.

I set `n` to two and it increases very fast every time it goes through the loop `n` doubles. It looks like it might be `2^n`.

Comment: Is `int i` the same variable in both cycles?

Comment: Does `n` really double each time through the first loop? Does `X` modify `i` as well as `n`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `i` increases by 1 each time through the first loop and `n` doubles each time through the loop, do you think the loop would ever terminate? (It probably would terminate when `2*n` overflows, but if you're operating in an environment that, say, automatically switches to a Big Integer package when numbers exceed the size of a primitive `int`, the program will probably simply crash when the system runs out of memory.)

But let's say that this is not what's happening and that `n` is constant. You don't say whether the execution time for `X` depends on the value of `i`, but let's say it does not.

The way to approach this is to answer the question: Since `i` increases by 1 each time through the first loop, how many iterations will be required to reach the loop termination condition (for `i` to be at least `2*n`)? The answer, of course, is O(n) iterations. (Constant coefficients are irrelevant for O() calculations.)

By the same reasoning, the second loop requires O(n) iterations.

Thus the overall program requires O(n + n) = O(n) iterations (and O(n) executions of `X`).

Comment: Is it better to pick a large or small number when picking a value for n?

Comment: @jmurphy - I don't understand that question. For complexity calculations, you don't "pick a value for `n`." Rather, you're trying to determine the functional form for the dependency of execution time on `n` (or some other measure of the "problem size", if `n` isn't the right measure).

Answer (score 0):

Your time complexity should be O(n). I assume you dont got any other loops where X is provided. You are using a n*2 which just doubles your n for this algorithm and your time complexity will then increase linear.

If you for an example using floyds algortihm which includes 3 nested for loops you can draw the conclusion that floyd have a time complexity of O(n^3) where n is the number of elements and 3 is represented by 3 nested for loops.

Comment: If I iterate through the algorithm for a value of n. I see that it is increasing, but how would I know that it is increasing linear and not exponential lets say.

Comment: Either you do an experimental analysis of the problem or a pure theoretical analysis of this.

For the experimental analysis you need to implement the algorithm and run the program with a variety size of data (n?). In C you can use time(give CPU time with decent accuracy) to be able to plot data  into a graph. From the graph you can draw a fairly accurate time complexity for the algorithm on YOUR machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may proceed like the following:

[image]

Note that you can ameliorate your algorithm (first loop) by avoiding to multiply `n` by `2` at every

Comment: Look at [this document](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt), starting from slide 8.

Comment: This test can be useful to you:
www.combineditorix.com